# Why is a select query working faster than a delete query in Oracle

Tags: oracle

I am concerned about the below queries:

```
select * from TABLEA where COLUMNA in (select....) and
COLUMNA in (select....)

delete from TABLEA where COLUMNA in (select....) and
COLUMNA in (select....)
```

Both have huge differences in running time.
The select query runs much faster than a similar delete query.

Comment: Delete does more work than select. But how many rows are found, and how many rows are deleted? (Which should be the same number, of course). Are you letting the select fetch all of the matching rows, or are you stopping it after the first chunk of data? What do the execution plans show?

Comment: run an oracle trace also.

Answer (score 2):

SELECT is just a PROJECTION. SELECT with FILTER PREDICATE is SELECTION. And both are completely different from DELETE, which is a DML.

Your question is too broad as it involves lot of stuff.

1. Select statement doesn't manipulate the data, DML does.
2. Select doesn't update the index keys, DML does.
3. DB writers are not involved with select, but with DML.
4. The OPTIMIZER acts differently for DIFFERENT OPERATIONS. Look at the explain plan at least.
   ...and many more reasons.

Two different contexts, no point in comparing.

**GUI ISSUES**

A select might look like faster when executed on GUI based tools like `SQL Developer` etc. which actually shows you the first fetched rows and not complete resultset. However, the DELETE needs to actually act on all the rows.

Answer (score 1):

Please check table structure and indexes. Maybe there a lot of ON DELETE CASCADE constraints or a lot of indices to delete. Indicies speed up select time and slow down delete time.